# Read a list of websites, get rid of HTML tags and write it all into a txt file

Tags: java, jsoup, urlconnection

I am trying to get a list of websites to be read once at a time and printed to a single file. I would also like the html tags to be extracted which I plan to use jsoup for HTML parsing. How would I do this before writing the content to the file?

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception`is quite self-explanative.

There is no `next` element because, quoting [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

> if no more tokens are available

Wrap your assignment in a a `while (myScanner.hasNext())` loop after initializing your `Scanner`.

Comment: Adding to the answer- in your case there is html from facebook do not match the delimiter pattern. For extracting text, consider using Tika